# Pandas minimum time where high is bigger than current high

Tags: python, pandas, date, time

I want to know within a pandas dataframe the first minimum time which the "high" is bigger than current high.

So for example, I have a dataframe with the following columns:

```
df["date"]
df["open"]
df["high"]
df["low"]
df["close"]
```

I want to know the MINIMUM date where the HIGH is bigger than Current high, this is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("spy10mindata.csv")
df.columns = [x.lower() for x in df.columns]
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'], dayfirst=True)
df = df.sort_values(["date"], ascending=[True])
df['just_date'] = df['date'].dt.date
df['just_date2'] = df['date'].dt.date
df['just_time'] = df['date'].dt.time
df["numdate"] = df['date'].dt.strftime("%Y%m%d").astype(int)
df["numtime"] = df['date'].dt.strftime("%H%M%S").astype(int)

df["try"] = np.where(df["high"] > df["high"))
```

""

But can't get over this problem for this analysis. If you can help I appreciate a lot

Comment: I can understand what you want to do wrt to the 'high' and current high, could you be more elaborate on what you want with the minimum date?

Comment: Yes sure, thank you for your time. So I want to know when the Minimum Time (just time column) where the high > than the current high. So lets say the high at 9:30:00 am is 10$ a share. I want to know the first time on the current day that it broke that High of day. So If it was at 10:00:00am I want the row to say 10:00:00. If that makes sense.

Comment: In such a case, what should the other values of df['try'] be? Would it be okay that initially, they are all set to 0 and whenever current high is > high, the row gets the new timestamp and for other rows, where current high is never > high, they remain 0?

Comment: For this specific strategy im testing, i really need to get the high that is bigger than the current row high. I was thinking maybe a loop through all the rows after the current row and get the first row that is bigger than the current high? Would that work?

Comment: if you know current high row number then use slice `[current_row+1:]` to get all rows after `current high` and then compare these rows with single value `current high` instead of comparing `results = df[ df["high"][current_row+1:] > currnet_high ]` and then you get first value `results[0]`

Comment: better create minimal example data so we could run it and test ideas. And show expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it can be done with rolling window but I have no idea.

I iterate rows to get current `high` and create `sub_df` with all rows after this value.

BTW: I use `random` to create some example data. Because I use `seed()` so you should get the same value in every execution - so values are not so random.

```
import pandas as pd
import random

random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date': pd.date_range(start='2020.05.01 12:00', periods=10, freq='d'),
    'high': [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(10)],
})

print(df)

df['higher_value'] = None
df['higher_data'] = None
df['higher_index'] = None

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print('current: row:', index, 'high:', row['high'])

    sub_df = df[index+1:] 
    higher_items = sub_df[ sub_df['high'] > row['high'] ]

    if len(higher_items):
        first = higher_items.iloc[0]
        print(' higher: row:', first.name, 'high:', first['high'])
        df['higher_value'][index] = first['high']
        df['higher_index'][index] = first.name
        df['higher_data'][index] = first['date']

    else:
        print(' higher: None')

    print('---')

print(df)
```

Before:

```
                 date  high
0 2020-05-01 12:00:00     6
1 2020-05-02 12:00:00     6
2 2020-05-03 12:00:00     0
3 2020-05-04 12:00:00     4
4 2020-05-05 12:00:00     8
5 2020-05-06 12:00:00     7
6 2020-05-07 12:00:00     6
7 2020-05-08 12:00:00     4
8 2020-05-09 12:00:00     7
9 2020-05-10 12:00:00     5
```

After:

```
                 date  high higher_value          higher_data higher_index
0 2020-05-01 12:00:00     6            8  2020-05-05 12:00:00            4
1 2020-05-02 12:00:00     6            8  2020-05-05 12:00:00            4
2 2020-05-03 12:00:00     0            4  2020-05-04 12:00:00            3
3 2020-05-04 12:00:00     4            8  2020-05-05 12:00:00            4
4 2020-05-05 12:00:00     8         None                 None         None
5 2020-05-06 12:00:00     7         None                 None         None
6 2020-05-07 12:00:00     6            7  2020-05-09 12:00:00            8
7 2020-05-08 12:00:00     4            7  2020-05-09 12:00:00            8
8 2020-05-09 12:00:00     7         None                 None         None
9 2020-05-10 12:00:00     5         None                 None         None
```

Comment: This solves it, thank you so much for your time ... The only issue I am having now with it is that it takes a lot of time to go through 1Mill rows. Thats the only thing, other than that this is the perfect solution.

Comment: iteration is not good for big data because it doesn't use internal C/C++ code. I was thinink about `rolling()` window but I don't know if it can use windos which size is changing for every row.